# Angular.js Accessing input field value inside controller $scope

Tags: angularjs

I've got a directive which defines a input field of type="file", which I can print and is not empty, namely:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <input type="file" file-model="myFile"/>
    {{myFile}} <-- this prints fine
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="saveData()">Post</button>
</form>
```

which I can see if called in the view

**app.js**

```
.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
        var modelSetter = model.assign;

        element.bind('change', function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
                modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
            });
        });
      }
    };
}]);
```

What I am trying to do now is access the field inside my controller:

```
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, fileUpload) {
    ...

    $scope.myFile; <-- initialise it 

    $scope.saveData = function() {

        var file = $scope.myFile;
        console.log(file); <-- prints out as undefined
    }



.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(){

        })
        .error(function(){

        });
    }
}]);
```

But *file* is **undefined**.

Any ideas why that would happen and how to access the value of the field?

Comment: Have you got the code for your directive as well?

Comment: Sure. I'll edit my question

Comment: Is `$scope.myFile` initialized in your controller? Otherwise it will only available in the view.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. Have you checked you have no errors in the console?

Comment: @naeramarth7: I have initialised it as $scope.myFile = {} and when trying to call the saveData() function, it prints still as Object {}

Comment: It would be an object because it has several members in there

Comment: Agreed it's an Object, but can't seem to understand why it's empty..

Comment: No console errors at any point during your app use?

Comment: No. So the directive works fine, and I just want to establish why printing $scope.myFile prints out as Object {}, since I also initialise it. Let me edit

Comment: So if you do $scope.myFile.name it does not give you anything? Also do you use Batarang, you can keep an eye on your $scope and see all its properties as they change [Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en)

Comment: Doing console.log($scope.myFile.name) and getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58617/discussion-between-daveloper87-and-claudiu-s).

Comment: I'm suspecting this problem is related to a nested scope. Could you show more html template to include the button that bind with the `saveDate()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bring in attribute values to your directive, I recommend doing it like so.

```
.directive('myDirective', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
    fileModel: '=fileModel'
    }
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = scope.fileModel;
        var modelSetter = model.assign;

        element.bind('change', function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
                modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
            });
        });
      }
    };
}]);
```

Note I changed your directive name since you already had an attribute with that name.

```
<input type="file" my-directive file-model="myFile"/>
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to do after you have the attribute value, but if you console.log(scope.fileModel) you can see what built in options are available.  This is an example of isolated scope within directives.

**Update with controller access**

To access within your controller, you could emit the value from your directive:

```
scope.$emit('myFile', scope.fileModel);
```

and then listen for the event in your controller:

```
$scope.$on('myFile', function (event, myFile) {
    $scope.myFile = myFile;
};
```

**Update with working fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/jonesmac82/376SS/26/

Comment: What I am trying to do is access the value of "myFile" in the controller.

Comment: Thanks, let me have a look :)

Comment: Still throwing undefined :(

Comment: Take a look at my fiddle and see if it helps you.  I think some of the complexity is that you need to get a file upload directive to work with files within angular.  Let me know if you need recommendations.

Comment: I just updated it again to show how you can structure your directive to handle object values.